# special characters are not getting populated correctly after reading from file

Tags: java, utf-8

```
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(f), "UTF-8");
```

According to rule it should return all specified characters as it is in stream. But it is not working fine. It is converting special characters into some invalid character strings.

Input characters : éÇüéâäàåçêëèïîìÄÅÉæ

output after reading from above method : ������������������� ��

Comment: Make sure the file you are reading has UTF-8 encoding or use the encoding of the file. Also it could just be the way you are writing the output.

Comment: i am using CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(isr,  ';');

Comment: Check if you're able to print the content by assigning the input characters to a string in the program. It's possible that your console where string is printed, is not using 'UTF-8'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This means that your stream is not in UTF-8. It may be in Windows-1252 or ISO 8859-1 or some other encoding.

The reader needs to use the encoding that the stream is encoded with, in order to read it properly.

Article worth noting: [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)

Comment: CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(isr,  ';'); This is what i am using to read data. I have CSV format file

Comment: That doesn't matter if `isr` is set up incorrectly. Your data is not encoded as UTF-8.

Comment: @VinaySharma: See Phylo's comment above (and my answer). Clearly, the data you're trying to read isn't encoded as UTF-8.

Comment: Data that i was reading from file not in UTF-8, I think.
Now i have copied same data to another file with same extension but now it is getting supported. previously i was having abc.csv from which i was reading data. same data i copied to another file with name xyz.csv now it is working fine.

Comment: @VinaySharma: *"Data that i was reading from file not in UTF-8, I think"* Yes, that's what *"This means that your stream is not in UTF-8"* means. Glad you sorted it out.